# Download file from Google Drive API in browser?

Tags: web-applications, download, google-drive-api

I am working with Google Drive API (raw HTTP on server-side). Now I need to let the user to download their file in browser (I want not to download to our server then send back to user).

According to this Guide: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads, `webContentLink` is needed. However I notice that not all files from `files.get` or `files.list` have it.

In browser, I cannot use FORM submit because I cannot create Authorization header. I cannot use AJAX too because they do not have CORS header in the response.

For DropBox API, they allow to move the Authorization headers into the query string. Is there anything similar for Google Drive?

EDIT: for additional information, I am willing to send access token to the browser, since we are going to work through HTTPS.

Comment: Will this information be helpful for you? https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c5b2811bce01cbcc26ffa357df496379

Comment: Interesting! I cannot try right now, but I notice this one though: `blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + e + "?alt=media", {`. It should be the same as the AJAX request. I'd have problem with CORS. Will check later when I am available.

Comment: ``UrlFetchApp.fetch()`` is run at Google server side. Will this be affected to CORS? I'm sorry for my poor knowledge.

Comment: @Tanaike Ah I see. Sorry I didn't notice .gs is server side code, thought it was a JS file. Yup, server side it should be no problem with CORS. However, my target is to download the file WITHOUT server proxy.

Comment: How about uploading from Google side to user using a trigger? You can chose the trigger. For example, those are web apps, e-mail and so on. I don't know whether this will lead to a solution. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`webContentLink` will be present only when the file is publicly shared. This means that file must have public access permissions.

Permissions can be created using [permissions/create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) API with params:

```
{
    'type': 'anyone',
    'role': 'reader',
    'withLink': True
}
```

Or permissions can be granted manually via UI:
[image]